# Image Positioning when resizing

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit

I have an image that is 1000x134 referred to as logo

I have an UIImageView that contains that logo as AspectFit

I have another view in the back

The user is allowed to pan, pinch, and rotate the logo to position it where ever they want on top of the background view

After they have positioned the logo, I then increase the size of the background view

**Problem**: After the background view's size gets increased, the position of the logo gets messed up.

**Question**: How do I scale the logo with the background view in order for it to appear in the same position?

Comment: Have you tried autolayout?

Comment: What would I have to do to make autolayout do the trick? #newb

Comment: add Contraint to UIImageView..it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `UIImageView` a subview of your background view. That would make it easy to resize the whole view, perhaps using `self.view.transform`.